# How to support list of standby smtp servers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, spring-cloud, hystrix

Currently our code for sending email messages looks like this:

```
@Override
public SendEmailResponse sendEmail(DtoEmailMessage dtoEmailMessage) {
    try {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mimeMessageCreator.createMessage(dtoEmailMessage);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        return SendEmailResponse.ok(channelEmailMessage.getEmailNotification().getTo(), mimeMessage.getMessageID());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MessagingException | RuntimeException e) {
       ...
    }
}
```

**What has to be improved ?**

I want to support a list of reserved smtp servers. So in case if **server_1** is failed for 2 or 3 times I wan to try with **server_2**. In case if **server_2** is failed - **server_3** is used etc.

I know about `spring-retry` and `spring-hystrix` but looks like they are not applicable for current task.

Is there any production ready solution for my task or it is better implement it on my own?

Comment: Usually your mail server should handle this for you. It should query the DNS for the [mx records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for the given recipient domain, and send according to their priority. It should retry as needed, or eventually bounce emails it cannot deliver. You can probably implement this on your own, but you may be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Robert agree with you in general but what if my main smtp server is down ?

Comment: if you have multiple smtp hosts, surely your network guys can supply you with some loadbalancer in failover configuration providing serveral hosts to allways be reachable via the same ip.

Answer (score 3):

It would better to handle multiple SMTP hosts managed by a load balancer however you can manage in your application code as well.

```
public class EmailService {
    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
    private final List<String> smtpServers;

    public EmailService(List<String> smtpServers) {
        this.smtpServers = smtpServers;
    }

    @Override
    public SendEmailResponse sendEmail(DtoEmailMessage dtoEmailMessage) {
        for (String smtpServer : smtpServers) {
            try {
                // create the email message
                MimeMessage mimeMessage = mimeMessageCreator.createMessage(dtoEmailMessage);
                JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl()
                mailSender.setHostName(smtpServer);
                mailSender.setPort(587);
                mailSender.setUsername("myusername");
                mailSender.setPassword("mypassword");
                // send the email message with automatic retry
                RetryExecutor executor = new RetryExecutor()
                    .withMaxRetries(MAX_RETRIES)
                    .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.fixedWait(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                executor.retry(() -> mailSender.send(mimeMessage));

                return SendEmailResponse.ok(channelEmailMessage.getEmailNotification().getTo(), mimeMessage.getMessageID());
            } catch (EmailException e) {
                // log the error and try the next SMTP server
            }
        }
        // all SMTP servers failed
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to send email message to any SMTP server");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me you have to implement circuit breaker design pattern.

I recommandé resilience4j :https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs.

Hystrix it no more supported, it's deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Better to use SMTP Connection Pool with all pool features (https://github.com/nithril/smtp-connection-pool).